# How to create a diverging data legend on a choroplet map?

Tags: html, leaflet, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choroplet map with diverging data (going from -0.7 to 0.7) and can't find a way so that my legend show the correct colors. The problem is because when colors are all positive signs is always > and is sequential. Now because I have negative numbers, it doesn't work anymore. How can I correct this?

```
    // get color depending on population differentiel value
function getColor(d) {
         return d > 0.7    ? '#b2182b' :
            d > 0.5    ? '#d6604d' :
            d > 0.3    ? '#f4a582' :
            d > 0.1    ? '#fddbc7' :
            d < -0.7   ? '#2166ac' :
            d < -0.5   ? '#4393c3' :
            d < -0.3   ? '#92c5de' :
            d < -0.1   ? '#d1e5f0' :    




                        '#f7f7f7';
}


var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [-0.7, -0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
        labels = [],
        from, to;

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        from = grades[i];
        to = grades[i + 1];

        labels.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            from + (to ? ' à ' + to : '+'));
    }

    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
    return div;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is because when colors are all positive signs is always > and is sequential. Now because I have negative numbers, it doesn't work anymore.

No, it's because you're mixing `>` and `<` without any good reason, instead of following a regular pattern of decreasing numbers, e.g.:

```
function getColor(d) {
 return d > 0.7    ? '#b2182b' :
        d > 0.5    ? '#d6604d' :
        d > 0.3    ? '#f4a582' :
        d > 0.1    ? '#fddbc7' :
        d > -0.1   ? '#d1e5f0' :    
        d > -0.3   ? '#92c5de' :
        d > -0.5   ? '#4393c3' :
        d > -0.7   ? '#2166ac' :
                     '#f7f7f7';
}
```

Now the stop points are aligned, so every stop point is the smallest value for the color range.

I'd go even further and store the stops and range colors in a data structure, correlating the smallest end of a range with the corresponding colour:

```
var stops = [
    { stop: 0.7, color: '#b2182b' },
    { stop: 0.5, color: '#d6604d' },
    { stop: 0.3, color: '#f4a582' },
    { stop: 0.1, color: '#fddbc7' },
    { stop: -0.1, color: '#d1e5f0' },
    { stop: -0.3, color: '#92c5de' },
    { stop: -0.5, color: '#4393c3' },
    { stop: -0.7, color: '#2166ac' },
    { stop: -Infinity, color: '#f7f7f7' },
];
```

And recreate the `getColor()` function by looping through that data structure:

```
function getColor(d) {
  for (var i in stops) {
    if (d > stops[i].stop) { return stops[i].color; }
  }
}
```

Note that all numbers are greater than `-Infinity`, so the last entry in that data structure shall work as the default case.

And create a legend by iterating through the same data structure, carrying over the range's upper stop from the previous step (and initializing that at `Infinity`, as that's the implicit upper stop for the first range):

```
var rangeMax = 'Infinity';
for (var i in stops) {
    var rangeMin = stops[i].stop.toString();
    var rangeColour = stops[i].color;

    labels.push(
        '<i style="background:' + rangeColour + '"></i> ' +
        rangeMin + ' à ' + rangeMax
    );

    rangeMax = stops[i].stop;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver! How can i change "-infinity" and "infinity" simple to "+" and "-"?  Right now I see: 

0.7 to Infinity
0.5 to 0.7
....
-Infinity to -0.7

Comment: I'd like to replace "0.7 to Infinity" by "More than 0.7" and "-Infinity to -0.7" by "Less than -0.7)". How can I do it?

Comment: It should be something trivial like `if (rangeMax === Infinity) {labels.push(rangeMin + '+')}` and `if (rangeMin === -Infinity) {labels.push(rangeMax + '-')}`

Comment: Where should I put the code exactly?

I tried this and it didn't work:


  var rangeMax = 'Infinity';
for (var i in stops) {
    var rangeMin = stops[i].stop.toString();
    var rangeColour = stops[i].color;

    labels.push(
        '<i style="background:' + rangeColour + '"></i> ' +
        rangeMin + ' à ' + rangeMax
    );

    rangeMax = stops[i].stop;
if (rangeMax === Infinity) {labels.push(rangeMin + '+')}
if (rangeMin === -Infinity) {labels.push(rangeMax + '-')}
}

  div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
  return div;
 };

 legend.addTo(map);

Answer (score 0):

`getColor(from + 1)` is the culprit. Because of the "+ 1", you will always be off your scale.

Note that even after removing it, you will be missing the lowest legend (< 0.7). You can handle it in a similar way as your highest legend.

Comment: How can I do it precisely?